# Posting a Thumbnail via the Vimeo API 3.2

Tags: vimeo-api

Two questions.

1) I'm trying to make my video's thumbnail a snapshot of a particular time in the video (2 seconds in). But, after following the instructions found at this link, when I run the following code, the thumbnail does not change, and the array is empty. I've tried different time formats, but not sure which is right. Any suggestions on what might going wrong?

https://developer.vimeo.com/api/playground/videos/%7Bvideo_id%7D/pictures

2) Is it possible to just upload the actual thumbnail file via the API?

```
    $video_data = $lib->request('videos/107110137/pictures', array('time' => '00.02'), 'POST');
    echo '<p>video_data after thumb change is <pre>';
    print_r($video_data);  

    //Prints out
    Array
    (
        [body] => 
        [status] => 0
        [headers] => Array
            (
            )

    )
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A status code of 0 means that curl was unable to reach the API servers.

The most common issue that leads to a 0 status code is HTTPS certificate problems. Take a look at http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/. I do NOT recommend their quick fix, because it will leave you more vulnerable to man in the middle attacks

If that doesn't work, add a [curl_error](https://www.php.net/curl_error) check to the _request function to find out more.

Comment: I have no problem making other API requests though and uploading via the API works fine too. If it was a certificate issue, wouldn't the other requests fail as well?

Comment: Correct, that is generally the case. Try my second suggestion, adding a curl_error check and let me know what response you receive from the server.

Comment: I pasted the code from your curl_error link above into the API call section in vimeo.php. It returned "Operation completed without any errors". So, still a no go. Could you please tell me if my time format is correct, and what SHOULD the return data look like when POSTing to that endpoint?

Comment: Status should be 201. Headers should contain a Location: <picture_uri>, along with a bunch of server + caching headers. The body should include a full picture response object, with a URI and an array of picture sizes.

Comment: Since it's not working, I'm still wondering about the time format that I'm entering. I don't see anything in the docs. To grab a frame at 2 seconds, I've tried '2', '00:00:02', '00:02'. I'm still getting the same empty array back. Is it expecting more variables? "0" isn't even a valid response code. I understand it's new functionality. Have user's actually gotten this to work.

Comment: 0 Means the request never reached our server, so the timecode isn't really relevant to this issue. It's supposed to be a float of seconds since start. So array("time"=>2) would be two seconds. Vimeo can probably help you better if you contact them at vimeo.com/help/contact and provide your full request and response. Runscope is a good tool to help track down every little piece of your request.